# Pull INT from Parse Database Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parse-platform, adapter

I'm hoping this will be a fairly simple thing. In my parse database I have an column called seconds. I do not know the proper syntax to pull it as a Int, I can only pull it as a string. Is there a good way to do this? I've looked into conversion methods but none of them address actually taking an int from a position in an adapter. Here is my code. Alternatively if someone can tell me how to convert that string afterwards in a new activity that would be great.

```
     listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
            Intent i = new Intent(Welcome.this,
                    MainActivity.class);

            // Pass data "name" followed by the position
            i.putExtra("Name", ob.get(position).getString("Name")
                    .toString());
            i.putExtra("Time", ob.get(position).getString("Time")
                    .toString());
            i.putExtra("Seconds", ob.get(position).getInt("Seconds")
                    );
            // Open SingleItemView.java Activity
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });






Second Activity


  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        btnStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
        textViewTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
        Timer = i.getStringExtra("Timer");
        textViewTime.setText(Timer);
        Name = i.getStringExtra("Name");
        Seconds = i.getIntExtra("Seconds");

        final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(180000,1000);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timer.start();
            }
        });
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: have you tried `getInt`

Comment: Yes I have but when I make it getInt("Seconds")
                                .toInt());   The second part errors out.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "getInt("Seconds")" without "toInt()".

Comment: If I do it that way how should I call it in the next activity? For instance for Strings it's...   Name = i.getStringExtra("Name"); How should I do it for an integer?

Comment: putExtra("key",  number);

and getIntExtra("key",  default).

Comment: The problem is that seconds doesn't exist as a variable on it's own. So in the other activity I can't just GeintIntEXtrag(seconds)  Don't you have to store columns column names with ""?  I will post up my  modified code for both activities.